# Datatable work with data in column

Tags: datatables

i have a table with a ajax/ssi database connection.

In one field of my database i store a number (1=male 0=female)

What i have do to, to change the given number from database (1/0) into the text "male" or "femal" or to chang it throug an icon.

And how i can use a filter for that (the visitor see not the value 1 or 0)?

Here is some code of the data.php

```
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'CONTACT_GROUP',   'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'KD_NO',           'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'TYPE',      'dt' => 2 ),
array( 'db' => 'ORG_NAME',  'dt' => 3 ),
array( 'db' => 'VORNAME',   'dt' => 4 ),
array( 'db' => 'NAME',      'dt' => 5 ),
array( 'db' => 'PLZ',       'dt' => 6 ),
array( 'db' => 'ORT',       'dt' => 7 )
);
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
* server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
*/
require( $vz.'assets/global/plugins/datatables/ssp.class.php' );
echo json_encode(
SSP::simple( $_GET, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
unset($modDB);
```

an this

```
$.fn.dataTable.pipeline = function ( opts ) {
// Configuration options
var conf = $.extend( {
    pages: 5,     // number of pages to cache
    url: '',      // script url
    data: null,   // function or object with parameters to send to the server
                  // matching how `ajax.data` works in DataTables
    method: 'GET' // Ajax HTTP method
}, opts );

// Private variables for storing the cache
var cacheLower = -1;
var cacheUpper = null;
var cacheLastRequest = null;
var cacheLastJson = null;

return function ( request, drawCallback, settings ) {
    var ajax          = false;
    var requestStart  = request.start;
    var drawStart     = request.start;
    var requestLength = request.length;
    var requestEnd    = requestStart + requestLength;

    if ( settings.clearCache ) {
        // API requested that the cache be cleared
        ajax = true;
        settings.clearCache = false;
    }
    else if ( cacheLower < 0 || requestStart < cacheLower || requestEnd > cacheUpper ) {
        // outside cached data - need to make a request
        ajax = true;
    }
    else if ( JSON.stringify( request.order )   !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.order ) ||
              JSON.stringify( request.columns ) !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.columns ) ||
              JSON.stringify( request.search )  !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.search )
    ) {
        // properties changed (ordering, columns, searching)
        ajax = true;
    }

    // Store the request for checking next time around
    cacheLastRequest = $.extend( true, {}, request );

    if ( ajax ) {
        // Need data from the server
        if ( requestStart < cacheLower ) {
            requestStart = requestStart - (requestLength*(conf.pages-1));

            if ( requestStart < 0 ) {
                requestStart = 0;
            }
        }

        cacheLower = requestStart;
        cacheUpper = requestStart + (requestLength * conf.pages);

        request.start = requestStart;
        request.length = requestLength*conf.pages;

        // Provide the same `data` options as DataTables.
        if ( $.isFunction ( conf.data ) ) {
            // As a function it is executed with the data object as an arg
            // for manipulation. If an object is returned, it is used as the
            // data object to submit
            var d = conf.data( request );
            if ( d ) {
                $.extend( request, d );
            }
        }
        else if ( $.isPlainObject( conf.data ) ) {
            // As an object, the data given extends the default
            $.extend( request, conf.data );
        }

        settings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
            "type":     conf.method,
            "url":      conf.url,
            "data":     request,
            "dataType": "json",
            "cache":    false,
            "success":  function ( json ) {
                cacheLastJson = $.extend(true, {}, json);

                if ( cacheLower != drawStart ) {
                    json.data.splice( 0, drawStart-cacheLower );
                }
                if ( requestLength >= -1 ) {
                    json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );
                }

                drawCallback( json );
            }
        } );
    }
    else {
        json = $.extend( true, {}, cacheLastJson );
        json.draw = request.draw; // Update the echo for each response
        json.data.splice( 0, requestStart-cacheLower );
        json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );

        drawCallback(json);        }
}};
// Register an API method that will empty the pipelined data, forcing an Ajax
// fetch on the next draw (i.e. `table.clearPipeline().draw()`)
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'clearPipeline()', function () {
return this.iterator( 'table', function ( settings ) {
    settings.clearCache = true;
} );
} );
//
// DataTables initialisation
//
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#ajax_table1').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
        url: 'data.php',
        pages: 5 // number of pages to cache
    } )
} );
} );
```

Hope anyboby could explain it - the examples on the datatable site wont help me much for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where and how you are fetching your data but just to give you an idea, in your php file you could do:

```
$gender = ($your_var==1) ? 'Male' : 'Female';
```

Then just pass $gender to your column

Comment: i've add the complete code of the php file, so how i can change the values from the database in this file?

Comment: I don't see at the moment any `php` file. This has to be the file you are using to fetch the data from your database

Comment: Ok :)  I am wondering from where you are getting this: `'dt' => 1`. Where is the number 1 coming from.

Comment: I see, you are getting data from `data.php` and this file I would like to see. Because the suggested code has to by applied there.

Comment: see on top - the code is under "of the data.php" - thats all

Comment: The data you are passing to the dataTable is coming from your database? If so let me see how do you fetch this data.

Comment: i do nothing, i have the html-table, the js file and the php file thats all

Comment: You say `Here is some code of the data.php` if so can you please show it all?

Comment: Additionally you say also: `In one field of my database i store a number (1=male 0=female)` So you have a database and you need to  retrieve this data from it in order to display it in your dataTable. If you are just trying dataTable and you are inputting the data in the columns array manually then you can not do what you wish untill you dont get the data from the table.